# Is there a way to find out how many times an image is covered?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

suppose for instance the curve:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x = f(t) \\ y=g(t) \end{bmatrix}$$

which is parametrized as above. I want to understand how many times the image of this curve in the $(x,y)$ plane is covered.

For instance If this is a 1-to-1 map then the whole image is covered only once. but if there exists $t_1, t_2 \in R$  such that $$(x_1,y_1)=(f(t_1),g(t_1))=(f(t_2),g(t_2))$$

Then I say that the point $(x_1,y_1)$ is covered twice. I want to know whether there exists a method for understanding the number of coverings of each subset of the image set. Does such a method exist?

Comment: What you are asking amounts to solving the system of simulaneous system of equations $$f(s)=f(t)$$ $$g(s)=g(t)$$ for the unknown ordered pair $(s,t)$. If you think of it that way, and if you have studied functions enough to know how impossible it is to solve systems of equations with complete generality, then you'll probably agree that this is hopeless in the generality that you have stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general method which would not depend on what $f$ and $g$ are ; indeed, given any number of finite points $P_1,...,P_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$, together with integers $k_1,...,k_n$ greater than $1$, you can find two polynomial functions $x,y$ such that the curve $(x(t),y(t))$ will go through $P_i$ exactly $k_i$ times for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$. To see that, you just need to use Lagrange interpolation on the coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$ of each $P_i$.

EDIT : I did not precise it before, but you can also decide on which time $t$ you will have $(x(t),y(t)) = P_i$